# Transferring Grub on MBR connection to different Linux distribution

Tags: grub, mbr

I had a Linux distribution which had installed grub on MBR.

Then I installed second Linux distribtion on a different partition but did not install grub in it.

Then I went to first Linux distribution and ran update-grub. So second Linux distribution also was picked up and is presented in menu at startup.

Now I want to remove first Linux distribution. How do I install grub in second Linux distribution so that it is linked to grub in MBR also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstall from working (not liveCD/DVD/USB) system - first find Ubuntu drive (example is drive sdb but use your drive not partitions):

```
sudo parted -l
```

if it's "/dev/sdb"  then just run:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

If that returns any errors run:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
```

Then just to redo menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I will try this and give feedback here. There is only one hard disk in this desktop, so it should be `/dev/sda`

Comment: Yes, it worked very well. There were no errors with `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and `sudo update-grub` picked up all systems. On rebooting, it is getting started into new grub installation of second Linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

The second installation of Linux should have grub support within it. Check whether `update-grub` command exists in the second installation e.g. `whereis update-grub`. If so, I think you can boot into the second Linux installation, delete the first and  then run `update-grub` to update your grub settings so that the first installation is no longer shown in grub menu at boot time. Take a backup first!

Comment: `update-grub` command is there. But, does `update-grub` command puts grub in MBR also? Otherwise, on booting, grub in MBR will look for first partition and not finding it may not boot!

Comment: The sudo update-grub does not reinstall to MBR, but updates grub menu with any changes to configuration files, scripts or additional systems.

Comment: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` is the command to install grub in mbr of sda. Then `sudo update-grub` to get all systems (as given in accepted answer).